# CoreData Field to a TableView

Tags: core-data, tableview

I checked before on the website, but no success. 
I Think this is pretty simple but, I could't find it. 
I'd like to update my TableView from a CoreData (Structure is entity : Projectors , Attribute : model)

Following code doesn't work (I would say of course, because something is missing, but I don't know). How can I load all data in my model to a NSMutableArray ?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"model" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;


mesProduits = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Even this doesn't work, could you please help me.                                 NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Projectors" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *frequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [frequest setEntity:entityDesc]; NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(model = %@)", mesProduits];
    [frequest setPredicate:pred];

Comment: Please add the additional information to your question, that would be much easier to read than from a comment. - And what does not work exactly? No results, the wrong results? Error messages?

Comment: In fact, I got no errors, but, mesProduits are empty. Where I'd like to have 6 strings in my array, I got @"0 objects". What I'd like to do is to take the model attributes from Projectors entity then store "model" attributes record in my TableView from mesProduits NSMutableArray.

Comment: I found the mistake it's working now.

Comment: If it's working now, please answer your own question and accept the answer-- then if someone else has the same problem, they may find your solution.